# Almacenar archivo en base de datos SQl Server 2008 AJAX C# ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-office

Estoy desarrollando esta parte de una página en donde necesito guardar  un  **archivo** (.xls ,.docx ,.png, etc) en una base de **SQl Server**, tambien necesito obtener las propiedades de este archivo como su nombre, tipo, tamaño; creo que ya casi lo tengo, pero sigo obteniendo este error por parte del servidor, al parecer todo lo que mando es **Null**. Estoy utilizando **Ajax / js** para pasar mi información al lado del servidor , estoy usando un **alert** solo para saber si estoy jalando bien la información. Pero mi error aparece en el lado del servidor.

(**Nota:** **Wiw** es mi username de mi página)

**Codigo del front end** (Creo que aquí no hay ningun problema)

```js
< script >
  function trymeplz() {
    var object = {};
    object.namePro = $("[id*=name]").val();
    object.file = $('#format').prop("files")[0];
    object.wiw = document.getElementById("wiw").value;

    alert("{'namePro' : '" + object.namePro + "'," +
      "'file' : '" + object.file + "' ," +
      "'wiw' : '" + object.wiw + "'" +
      "}");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")',
      data: "{'namePro' : '" + object.namePro + "'," +
        "'file' : '" + object.file + "' ," +
        "'wiw' : '" + object.wiw + "'" +
        "}",
      success: function(response) {
        alert("at least Ajax looks fine" + response);
      },
      Error: function(response) {

        alert("something got wrong" + response);
      }
    });
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.testsoru @{ ViewBag.Title = "Kyo_2"; }

<div class="container">
  <div class=row "">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="NombreDeProyecto" id="name" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Formato</td>
            <td>
              <label>Formato: </label> <input type="file" id="format" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wiw</td>
            <td>
              <p>
                @Session["Wiw"]
                <input type="text" class="hidden" id="wiw" value="@Session[" WiW "]" />
              </p>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" onclick="trymeplz()" name="name" value="trymeplz" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codigo del back end** (View **test** es una vista no se preocupen por ella)

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KyoTest(testsoru test, HttpPostedFileBase[] files) {

  string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

  foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files) {

    int size = file.ContentLength;
    string fname = file.FileName;
    int position = fname.LastIndexOf("\\");
    fname = fname.Substring(position + 1);

    string contentType = file.ContentType;
    byte[] fileData = new byte[size];
    file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
      string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
        " VALUES(@Name,@wiw,@format,@Size,@FName,@Type)";

      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query)) {

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", test.name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", test.wiw);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@format", test.formato);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", size);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", contentType);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        con.Close();
      }
    }
  }


  return View(test);
}
```

Mi error aparece justo por aquí en el lado del servidor, tambien les dejo una vista del diseño de mi tabla y de mi modelo de datos para un mejor entendimiento. 

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modelo de datos**

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models {
  public class testsoru {
    internal HttpFileCollection Files;
    internal HttpPostedFileWrapper file;

    public int id {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string name {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string wiw {
      get;
      set;
    }
            public HttpPostedFileWrapper formato {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

Muchas grácias a toda la comunidad, son geniales :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no se esta enviando correctamente con jQuery la informacion mediante POST, la forma mas sencilla de resolver el problema es modificando el jQuery y el html.

Encierra tu html en un formulario:

```
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.testsoru @{ ViewBag.Title = "Kyo_2"; }
<form id="uploadForm">
<div class="container">
  <div class=row "">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="NombreDeProyecto" id="name" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Formato</td>
            <td>
              <label>Formato: </label> <input type="file" id="format" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wiw</td>
            <td>
              <p>
                @Session["Wiw"]
                <input type="text" class="hidden" id="wiw" value="@Session[" WiW "]" />
              </p>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" onclick="trymeplz()" name="name" value="trymeplz" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y después modifica el javascript con jQuery para utilizar el objeto FormData

```
var form = new FormData($("#uploadForm")[0]);
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert("at least Ajax looks fine" + response);
        },
        error: function(er){
            alert("something got wrong" + response);
        }
});
```

Esto simplificara mucho las cosas.

Documentacion del objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: probé tu sugerencia y desafortunadamente sigo obteniendo el mismo error u.u